# knockout.js - click binding argument get text of event sender

Tags: data-binding, click, knockout.js

I have this link on my page - for a find entry by first letter.  I want to pass the text of the anchor tag into knockout's click event inside the data-bind attribute.  Is this possible?

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.getManageableEntries()><%= Convert.ToChar(i + 65)%></a></li>

// here's my javascript method in my knockout view model
function ManageEntriesViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    this.getManageableEntries = function(firstLetter) {
        // i want to pass in the text of the <a> tag as the 'firstLetter' variable
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably have the anchor's text as an observable in your view model. Then you just need to access that observable (instead of directly accessing the anchor element's text). This gives you maximum flexibility.

I made 2 examples because I wasn't sure how you're structuring your view model objects.

Both work fine: 
[example-1](http://jsfiddle.net/3pduc/) , 
[example-2](http://jsfiddle.net/26Q7z/)

If you really want to have the first-letter extraction in your data-bind attribute, you could either put an anonymous function there, or bind your function with an argument, like I did in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJCVr/).

I hope one of these approaches fits your needs.

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for because I don't want the value inside the text to be something in my view model.  Ideally, I'd like to just read the value of the text directly out of the anchor element.

Comment: If you have data in your view that you want to access/manipulate in your code, but you don't want this data in a viewmodel, then I think what you're looking for is not KO functionality.. you could just do that with a click binding. (e.g. with jquery: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26Q7z/2/))

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've found it by now, Levitt, but here's what you're looking for...

See "Note 2: Accessing the event object, or passing more parameters" here:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Just pass add'l params via a click-bound function.  Be sure to include the first param as $data, regardless of how you render.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. In your HTML tag that you don't want to be explicitly "data-bound" to some observable in the viewmodel, assign a `click` or `change` event to the HTML tag. Then wrap your actual function in a dummy function and pass in the two parameters `data` and `event`. **You must have both**, or it will fail. In my case I used a change event. See below:

**HTML:**

`<input data-bind="event: { change:function(data, event) { $parent.SomeFunction(data, event) }}"></input>`

And then in your JavaScript function, you can access the text of the `<input>` like so:

**JavaScript:**

```
function SomeFunction(data, event)
{
    var inputValue = event.currentTarget.value;
    alert(inputValue);
}
```

So every time that I write text in the `<input>` field, `SomeFunction()` will be called and will alert the text that I have just written.